# CSS/Javascript <ul> Menu Pop Up

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a simple menu pop-up effect using anchors within a div and unordered lists.

I want the html to look something like this:

```
<div class="info">
 <a href="#">Link</a> | 
 <a onclick="menu('id1');">Another Link</a>
 <ul id="id1" class="submenu">
  <li><a href="dfhdfh">Stuff</a></li>
  <li><a href="aetjetjsd">Other</a></li>
  <li><a href="etetueb">Hooray</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript [pretty simple, not the problem, i don't think]:

```
function menu(id) {
    var myLayer = document.getElementById(id);
    if (myLayer.style.display == "none" || myLayer.style.display == "") {
        myLayer.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        myLayer.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The css is I believe where the problem is:

```
.info ul .submenu
{
 border: solid 1px #000;
 border-top: none;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 position: relative;
 top: 4px;
 width: 150px;
 padding: 6px 0;
 clear: both;
 z-index: 2;
 display: none;
}

.info ul .submenu li
{
 background: none;
 display: block;
 float: none;
 margin: 0 6px;
 border: 0;
 height: auto;
 line-height: normal;
 border-top: solid 1px #00ff00;
}

.info .submenu li a
{
 background: none;
 display: block;
 float: none;
 padding: 6px 6px;
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 height: auto;
 color: #ff0000;
 line-height: normal;
}

.info .submenu li a:hover
{
 background: #0000ff;
}
```

I don't really know how to create the css on the ul so that if appears over the underlying text.  I can't get it in the right spot.

I just want to click the `<a>` tag and a menu will pop up directly below the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I see you have ".info ul .submenu" for the first two and not the second two.  Was this intentional?  (I'm not a CSS guy, so I am just asking.)  Also, the first set has display: none, not sure if that's intended.

Comment: You have a white space between ul and .submenu.  This means, that CSS is selecting any element inside of that ul with class .submenu.  I believe you wanted ul.submenu, without the space.  This means, that CSS would select and ul with class .submenu.

Comment: .info ul .submenu: Styles the <ul> tag 

.info ul .submenu li: Styles the <li> tag within the <ul> tag

.info .submenu li a: Styles the <a> within an <li> tag within an tag with .submenu as a class.

The display:none; attempts to hide the panel until it is clicked.  When it is clicked, the display is set to block.

Comment: @dimskiy: You're right about the space.  It doesn't fix THE problem but it now correctly applies the style.  The panel still isn't in the right place.

Comment: @Jim Roboju:  I just tried out your code with white spaces removed as I suggested earlier.  It works fine.  The menu shows/hides under the <a> with onclick.  Is there something else that you're trying to achieve here?  I don't think I fully understand your question

Comment: @dimskiy: The menu hides under the <a>, but when it is visible it pushes whatever is in the <a> to the top.  The <a> is not on the same level as the other <a>.  The <a> stuff moves upward, I want it to remain in the same spot.

Comment: @Jim Roboju: What browser are you testing this in?  I tried FF and IE7, bot <a>'s remain in the same spot on show/hide.

Comment: @dimskiy: You're correct! I had a bad div.info class that was screwing stuff up.  The code I presented, more or less, works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your CSS:

```
.info ul.submenu
{
border: solid 1px #000;
border-top: none;
background-color: #fff;
position: relative;
top: 4px;
width: 150px;
padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
z-index: 2;
display: none;
}

.info ul.submenu li
{
display: block;
border: none;
border-top: solid 1px #00ff00;
}

.info ul.submenu li a
{
display: block;
padding: 6px 0px 6px 4px;
color: #ff0000;
}

.info ul.submenu li a:hover
{
background: #0000ff;
}
```

Let me know if the problem is still there.  Like I said earlier, I don't see "a"'s moving on show/hide.

---

EDIT:  Ok. I'm much more stronger with jQuery as oppose to plain javascript.  If you cannot use jQuery for whatever reason, I have to leave it up to you to perform the same with plain js.  Sorry!

HTML:

```
<ul class="root">
  <li>
    <div class="menuHeader">Something 1</div>
    <ul class="parent">
      <li>asdf 1.1</li>
      <li>asdf 1.2</li>
      <li>asdf 1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="menuHeader">Something 2</div>
    <ul class="parent">
      <li>asdf 2.1</li>
      <li>asdf 2.2</li>
      <li>asdf 2.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="menuHeader">Something 3</div>
    <ul class="parent">
      <li>asdf 3.1</li>
      <li>asdf 3.2</li>
      <li>asdf 3.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.info ul.root > li
{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  border:solid 1px blue;
  padding:5px;
}
.info ul.parent
{
  padding:0px;
  display:none;
}
.info .menuHeader
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.info li
{
  list-style: none;
}
```

Javascript (utilizing jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menuHeader').click(function(event) {
    $('.parent').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.parent').show();
  });
});
```

I included only the functional kind of stuff in the CSS.  Obviously, you need different look, so you may play with colors on your own.  Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: This works. Another issue has arrisen however. The popup is always left aligned with the .info. How does the popup work if there are two uls in the same div?  I would like the popup to be underneath the <a>s not always to the far left.

Comment: @Jim Roboju:  Are you planning to have a separate submenu for every parent?  Or are you going to populate the same <ul> with different options every time a different parent is clicked?

Comment: I basically wanted to be able to click on links within p/div tags and have a menu popup.  I don't really want to use uls as my content will not always be regimented.

Comment: Better response: Yes I would like a different sub menu for every parent. Id ideally like the parents to just be <a> tags. I don't want to nest the parents instead uls or divs as I'd like the ability to use these menus within <p> tags. Maybe thats not possible though.  I've been working on this for the better part of 3-4 hours and most of the examples I find want the parents strucuted into some sort of <div>Parent 1</div><div>Parent 2</div> format.

Comment: Give me a few minutes.  I'll put some code together real quick.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I ended up setting the absolute position with javascript using a function with 2 inputs: (this, id).  Works pretty well.  I now need to figure out the click away disapear part.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your work!  I don't use jquery because I'm just learning javascript.  In time :).

Answer (score 0):

Try:
ul .submenu ==> ul.submenu

in the css.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple of changes to ur css -
i am directly refering to submenu class

```
.submenu
    {
        list-style: none;
        display: none;
        border: solid 1px #000;
        border-top: none;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: relative;
        top: 4px;
        margin:0;
        padding: 0 5px;
        width: 150px;
        clear: both;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .submenu li
    {
        background: none;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 6px;
        border: 0;
        height: auto;
        line-height: normal;
        border-top: solid 1px #00ff00;
    }
    .submenu li a
    {
        background: none;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        padding: 6px 6px;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        height: auto;
        color: #ff0000;
        line-height: normal;
    }
    .submenu li a:hover
    {
        background: #0000ff;
    }
```